# What's the formal name of this diagram?

Tags: software, diagrams

[image]

I'd also want to know how can I draw them.

Comment: [online railroad diagram drawer](http://railroad.my28msec.com/rr/ui)

Comment: Also sometimes called "grammar diagrams", I think.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That looks like [SQLite's syntax diagrams](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html).

[Their FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q25) says:

> How are the syntax diagrams (a.k.a. "railroad" diagrams) for SQLite generated?

The answer is a link to [this wiki page on "Generating Syntax Diagrams Using Tk"](http://wiki.tcl.tk/21708).

The wiki links [to this Tcl source code](http://www.sqlite.org/docsrc/doc/tip/art/syntax/bubble-generator.tcl?mimetype=text/plain) for generating the diagrams.

Answer (score 7):

That is a [syntax diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram).  I think I first saw them in Grogono's ["Programming in Pascal"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201120704), from 1980, but they were used in [Wirth's 1973 report on PASCAL](http://e-collection.library.ethz.ch/eserv/eth:3059/eth-3059-01.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

Just a hint for LaTeX-Users:

The [rail-package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/rail) allows the generation of such rail-diagramms with (La)TeX.

You may check [TeX.SX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39751/6563) for an example.